# Calling a function inside a jQuery event

Tags: jquery

```
$(function () {

    alert($("#fruit").val());
    $("#fruit").click(change2());

});

var apple1 = ("<p>The orange is the fruit of the citrus species Citrus × sinensis in the family Rutaceae. The fruit of the Citrus sinensis is called sweet orange to distinguish it from that of the Citrus aurantium, the bitter orange.</p>");
var orange1 = ("<p>LOL I AM AN ORANGE </p>")
var grape1 = ("<p>A grape is a fruiting berry of the deciduous woody vines of the botanical genus Vitis. Grapes can be eaten raw or they can be used for making wine, jam, juice, jelly, grape seed extract, raisins, vinegar, and grape seed oil.</p>");
var strawberry1 = ("<p>The garden strawberry is a widely grown hybrid species of the genus Fragaria. It is cultivated worldwide for its fruit. The fruit is widely appreciated for its characteristic aroma, bright red color, juicy texture, and sweetness.</p>");
var cantaloupe1 = ("<p>Cantaloupe refers to a variety of Cucumis melo, a species in the family Cucurbitaceae. Cantaloupes range in size from 500 g to 5 kg. Originally, cantaloupe referred only to the non-netted, orange-fleshed melons of Europe.</p>");

function change2() {
    alert("Test2");
    var select = $("#fruit").val();
    switch (select) {
    case "apple":
        $("#description").html(apple1);
        alert("apple");
        break;

    case "orange":
        $("#description").html(orange1);
        alert("orange");
        break;

    case "grapes":
        $("#description").html(grape1);
        alert("grapes");
        break;

    case "cantaloupe":
        $("#description").html(cantaloupe1);
        alert.ht("melon");
        break;

    case "strawberry":
        $("#description").html(strawberry1);
        alert("straw");
        break;

    case "none":
        alert("reddit is cool");
        $("#description").html("<p> wow wow wow much doge </p>" + apple1);
        break;
    }
    alert("end");
}
```

I am trying activate the switch statement, when #fruit the select menu is changed. For some reason no matter what I try i does not work. I want to change it to the var. So we you choose apple in the web page, it should run through the switch statement and print out var apple1. For deafult its set as "none" so when starting up it automatically runs the "none" case. This is just for testing sake.

Comment: *"it does not work"*: What exactly do you mean by that? What happens and what do you expect to happen? The better you explain the problem, the easier it is for us to help you, and for others (in the future) to recognize if they have the same problem.

Comment: "it does work" as in when I select a different value on the drop down menu, the function/.click function does not execute.

Answer (score 0):

This is the syntax for writing an event handler function.

`$("#fruit").click(change2);`

Remove the braces `()`

or you could write the longer version of the same thing as above.

```
$("#fruit").click(function() {
    change2();
});
```

Comment: You should explain the why as well